# Write a function to check if its parameter (positive integer) is a perfect square. Then apply this function to a vector of positive integers

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am new to functions and right now I am trying to understand them so please go easy on me if you see some "noob" mistakes. I would really appreciate some help with this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int check(int a[], int n, int i)
{
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (a[i] == j * j)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n, a[100], i;
    printf("\nThe size:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("\na[%d]=", i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);

        if (check(a, n, i) == 1)
            printf("%d is a perfect square\n", a[i]);
        else
            printf("%d is not a perfect square\n", a[i]);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

I succeeded in making it run but something isn't right no matter the input (1,4,5,9...) it will always print: `is not a perfect square`.

Comment: Remember to pay very close attention to your indentation and keep it consistent. C is a very unforgiving language, so a missing set of `{ }` brackets can dramatically alter how the program behaves.

Comment: Why are you passing in an array+index combination to `check` when you could just pass in a number? That function never iterates over the array, it doesn't even need to know there's an array involved.

Comment: Hint: Why are you exiting your `check` function on the first iteration of the loop regardless of success or failure?

Comment: The `if/else` in the function will return `0` or `1`  on the very first `j` without going further.

Comment: You didn't write a function which checks if its parameter (positive integer) is a perfect square. Start with this first. Then once it works, deal with the vector part. Hint: the prototype of the `check` function is: `int check(int number)`

Comment: I think what your teacher wants is `int issquare(int n);` to check a single number and later call that in loop with the elements of an array: `int count = 0; for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) if (issquare(arr[i])) count++; printf("array has %d squares.\n", count);`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to pass only a number to the function instead. To do that, you can simply do:

```
int check(int value, int n)
{
    for (int j=0; j<n ; j++)
        if(value==j*j)
            return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

and call the function like this:

```
check(a[i], n)
```

Now, you are not passing the whole array, but only a number, i.e. the i-th number of it.

At this point, you have a function to check *one number*. Think what you need to do, to check a collection of numbers. How would you apply that `check()` to every number of your vector?

PS: An important and fundamental note is that you should *indent your code*, since it makes everything much more readable (for example, curly brackets get aligned).

---

Appendix:

You could make your initial function work like this:

```
int check(int a[],int n,int i )
{
    int j;
    for (j=0; j<n ; j++)
    {
        if(a[i]==j*j)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

so that you don't stop looping over when the condition is not mean, but will continue checking the other entries as well.

However, I strongly recommend using my suggestion above.

Comment: I rewrote the program and it works for both a number and the vector but I also need to copy each perfect square into a new vector and I was thinking of adding a parameter to count how many there are and create a for with it for the 2nd vector but something isn't right, I'm open to ideas if you have some

Comment: The parameter `n` in this function (`check`) comes from outer space. What does it mean? why is it needed? *Write a function to check if its parameter (positive integer) is a perfect square* where's `n` in this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

> Write a function to check if its parameter (positive integer) is a perfect square

What is needed is:

```
bool check_if_perfect_square(unsigned n);
```

Simple find the [integer square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root). Integer square root routines are not too hard to code. Maybe:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

// Square root of t round toward 0
unsigned uisqrt(unsigned t) {
  unsigned s, b;
  for (b = 0, s = t; s; b++, s >>= 1) {
    ;
  }

  s = 1u << (b >> 1);
  if (b & 1) {
    s += s >> 1;
  }

  do {
    b = t / s;
    s = (s + b) >> 1;
  } while (b < s);

  return s;
}
```

If you do not like that advanced approach, code could slowly iterate. No need to iterate to `i<n`, but to `i <= n/i`.

```
unsigned uisqrt(unsigned n) {
  unsigned i = 0;
  if (n > 0) {
    for (i = 1; i <= n/i; i++) {
      ;
    }
    i--; 
  }
  return i;
}
```

Then the check is easily

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool check_if_perfect_square(unsigned n) {
  unsigned sr = uisqrt(n);
  return sr*sr == n);
}
```

---

> Then apply this function to a vector of positive integers

Armed with a `check_if_perfect_square()`, simply iterate over the array.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void square_root_test_array(unsigned *a, size_t array_length) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i<array_length; i++) {
    if (check_if_perfect_square(a[i])) {
      printf("%u is a perfect square\n",a[i]);
    } else {
      printf("%d is not a perfect square\n",a[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Sample use

```
int main() {
  printf("\nThe size:\n");
  unsigned n = 0;
  scanf("%u",&n);
  unsigned a[n];

  for(unsigned i=0; i<n; i++) {
    printf("a[%u] = ",i);
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
  }

  // Now test array
  square_root_test_array(a, n);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You function does not work because you only make a single test and return `0` if `a[i]` is not `0`.

You should write the function `check` to take a single argument `n` instead of the array, its length and an index value, and call this function for each element of the array

Here is a simplistic version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int check_square(int n) {
    for (j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
        if (j * j == n)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int n, a[100];

    printf("Enter the array size: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n <= 0)
        return 1;
    if (n > 100)
        n = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("a[%d]=", i);
        if (scanf("%d", &a[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (check(a[i]))
            printf("%d is a perfect square\n", a[i]);
        else
            printf("%d is not a perfect square\n", a[i]);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

The above code is inefficient and only works for small numbers as `j * j` may easily exceed the range of type `int`.  You should stop the loop when `j` exceeds the square root, which can be tested as `j <= n / j`, assuming `j` is not `0`.

Here is an improved version:

```
int check_square(int n) {
    if (n < 0)
        return 0;
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    for (j = 2; j <= n / j; j++) {
        if (j * j == n)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A more efficient version would use a binary interpolation:

```
int check_square(unsigned n) {
    unsigned lo, hi;
    if (n < 4) {
        return n == 0 || n == 1;
    }
    for (lo = 2, hi = n / 2; hi - lo > 1;) {
        unsigned mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        unsigned quo = n / mid;
        if (quo <= mid) {
            lo = quo;
            hi = mid;
        } else {
            lo = mid;
            hi = quo;
        }
    }
    return lo * lo == n;
}
```